# Creating a surface from a path of 3D cubic bezier curves

Tags: graphics, 3d, bezier

I have a list of cubic bezier curves in 3D, such that the curves are connected to each other and closes a cycle.

I am looking for a way to create a surface from the bezier curves. Eventually i want to triangulate the surface and present it in a graphic application.

Is there an algorithm for surfacing a closed path of cubic bezier segments?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you only know part of the details of the surface (given by the Bezier curves) and you've to extrapolate the surface out of it. As a simple example I'm imagining a bunch of circles in 3D with the center and radius that will be reconstructed into a sphere.

If this is the case you can use [level sets](http://math.berkeley.edu/~sethian/2006/Explanations/level_set_explain.html). With level sets, you define a bunch of input parameters that defines the force exerted by the external factors on your surface and the 'tension' of the surface.

Crudely put, level sets define the behaviour of surface as they expand(or contract ) over time. As it expands it tries to maintain it's `smoothness` while meeting other boundary conditions - like 'sticking' to the circles in this case. So if you want a sphere from bunch of circles, the circles will exert a great force, while the surface will also be very tense.

[Physbam](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~jteran/project.html) has an open source implementation of level sets.

[CGAL](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/packages.html#PartMeshing) and [PCL](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/#surface-tutorial) also provide a host of methods that generate surfaces from things such as points sets and implicit surface. You may be able to adapt one of them for your use.

You can look into the algorithms they use if you want to implement one on your own. I think at least one of them use the [Poisson Surface Reconstruction](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/hoppe/poissonrecon.pdf) algorithm.